# issue with informatica variables in unix

Tags: variables, informatica

I have a issue with informatica environmental variables.
the variables are not getting displayed in unix.
[root@******]# su infadm
bash-4.2$ echo $PMEXTERNALPROCDIR

bash-4.2$

I check the variables session in admin console and all the path are defined correctly.
what could be the reason and what should i do if i have to see the value?

Answer (score 0):

You probably started the integration service as a user other than infadm . Su to the user who starts the informatica service and check the variable value. If you don't know who started the services you could create a command task in workflow manager to run following command

```
whoami | cat > /home/youruser/whoisrunninginformatica
```

Just make sure you open the permissions on your home directory before executing it. If you dont care who is running the service you could use same strategy to cat the variable value itself.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use a specific user for Informatica Services, something like "ipcuser".

Change/login with that user and create the Informatica home folder, also change the ownership to the that user.

Once created, let's assume that you are using bash. Search and/or create the file .bash_profile

Edit all the variables in that file and work with the variables like this:

```
PATH=${PATH}:~/bin
export PATH
```

Once you edit use `source .bash_profile` and/or logout and login again.

Review the variables with `env | grep PATH`